# wpf submenu not working when coming from resources

Tags: wpf, menuitem, submenu

I would like to use wpf menu items, defined in a resource, as menu and submenu. It works when used as a usual menu, but I can't make it work on a submenu.

Here is a sample code:

```
    <Grid Background="Transparent">

    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:Object}" x:Key="Extensions">
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Extension MenuItem 1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Extension MenuItem 2" />
            <MenuItem Header="Extension MenuItem 3" />
        </x:Array>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <MenuItem Header="Standard MenuItem 1" />
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource Extensions}" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Extension" >
                        <CollectionContainer Collection="{StaticResource Extensions}" />
                    </MenuItem>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>

</Grid>
```

And the result I get:

[image: Submenu not as expected]

Can someone give me the correct wpf syntax ?

Tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `ItemSource` and bind the resource correctly :

```
<MenuItem Header="Extension" >
   <MenuItem.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
     <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Extensions}}"  />
    </CompositeCollection>
   </MenuItem.ItemsSource>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Perfect. Only the itemsSource and CompositeCollection was missing. Binding was correct.